# c++ curl response after redirects

Tags: c++, curl

so I am coming from python so c++ is pretty difficult to transition into so pardon anything that might be simple.

I am looking to get a response code of a website after it redirects and I currently have this after a few google searches

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_GET_ALL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

curl_easy_perform(curl);

long http_code;

curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);

cout << http_code << endl;
```

but this only returns the initial response code. I might be missing something basic but I have a python script very similar to this and it prints a differen't response code than this program.

Comment: Use: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L); `

Comment: you're not checking that curl_easy_getinfo succeeds tho. like, it probably isn't, but why take the chance? i use ```#define ecurl_easy_getinfo(curl,info,...){ \
 CURLcode ret=curl_easy_getinfo(curl,info,__VA_ARGS__); \
 if(unlikely(ret!=CURLE_OK)){ \
   myerror(EXIT_FAILURE,errno,"curl_easy_getinfo failed to get info %i. CURLCode: %i curl_easy_strerror: %s\n", info, ret, curl_easy_strerror(ret));   \
 } \
}

``` - but that's for C, a runtime_exception would probably fit better in C++

Comment: @hanshenrik This is just a snippet, in the full program it checks if every succeeds but that is irrelevant to the redirect question.